# The pixel in iframe in chrome dev tool is bigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have an HTML with iFrame. The `<div>` container and `iframe` have the width of `381px`

```
<div class="container" style="width: 381px; height: 282px; overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 20px;">
    <iframe id="my-iframe" src="some-link.html" style="width : 381px; height : 100%;  border: 0px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

On `some-link.html`

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Flip Ad</title>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
      <style>
        html, body {
            width : 100%;
            height : 100%;
            padding : 0px;
            margin : 0px;
            font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif!IMPORTANT;
        }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div style="background-color : orange; height : 20px; width : 370px">this div</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

As you can notice the `div` has `370px` width (which is slightly shorter that the iframe) but it renders much longer in chrome dev tools (mobile view).

[image]

It is okay if not on mobile view. on a I'm wondering what is the problem here?

I tagged `javascript` and `jquery` because I am open if that is the solution.

[image]

Comment: From the look of it the scroll is too long for this to be the solution, but my first thought  was to check the `html` and `body` margins in the iframe.

Comment: The scroll is the problem. There should be no scroll coz the content is of the iframe is shorter.

Comment: The `padding` and `margin` are set to `0px` on the iframe.

Comment: I agree! When you inspect the iframe, what widths are shown?

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: Where does this border-radius come from? Are you sure it's the scrollbar of the iframe and not of your main <body>?  If the screen is smaller than the content, sounds normal you get a scrollbar.

Comment: I removed the `border-radius` on the second screenshot. the scroll bar is the iframe because when you drag the bar to left, the div is still there. @Kaiido

Comment: I also tried `overflow : hidden;` adding on body and html of the `some-link.html` and the scroll bar was gone